# How to register user info from android studio to 000webhost.com database(php)?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm trying to insert user info to 000webhost database (phpMyAdmin) from android studio. My database is connected however I can't post anything in the database. Can somebody help me with that?

```
    registerbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            register();
});
}

public void register() {

    FirstName = firstname.getText().toString();
    LastName = lastname.getText().toString();
    Email = email.getText().toString();
    Password = pass.getText().toString();
    Password2 = pass2.getText().toString();
    BackGround bg = new BackGround();
    bg.execute(FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, Password2);


}

class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String firstname = params[0];
        String lastname = params[1];
        String email = params[2];
        String pass = params[3];
        String pass2 = params[5];
        String data = "";
        int temp;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://lovethesnipers.000webhostapp.com/register.php");
            String urlParams = "firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname +
                    "&email=" + email + "&pass=" + pass + "&pass2=" + pass2;

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            while ((temp = is.read()) != -1) {
                data += (char) temp;

            }
            is.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();

            return data;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception: " + e.getMessage();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if (s.equals("")) {
            s = "Register Successful.";
        }
        Toast.makeText(AppRegisterActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

}
```

This is my register.php in server side

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require "init.php";

$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$pass2 = $_POST["pass2"];
//$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users_info (id,firstname,  
  lastname, email, pass, pass2) VALUES (null,?, ?, ?, ?,?)");

$sql = "INSERT INTO users_info(id, firstname, lastname, email, pass, pass2)  VALUES (?, ?, ?,?,?)";

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, "siss", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $pass, $pass2);
mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);

if(!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
echo '{"Unable to save the data to the database"}';

}


?>
```

My database name is table name is user_info and the fields are id, firstname, lastname, email, pass, and pass2. It is connected but every time I hit the register button it doesn't pass the value to the database. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: 000webhost are you talking about free 000webhost hosting? by phpMyAdmin?? do you mean mysql?

Comment: Hi, Matas Lesinskas, yes I'm talking about the free web host 000webhost. I want to use phpMyAdmin database. Any Idea?

Comment: Try to quote pass  like this ` pass `, also if you use bindings and so on, use with prepare, and other stuff.
Just do it like in http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
I dont use sintax like this, because its hard to read, so I cant directly point error.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing $_GET method not $_POST, if you are sending data in url use $_GET.
Soo just change $_POST to $_GET.